# Mono for Android Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, android, html, html-parsing

A user here, gave me a HtmlAgilityPack for Android. My question is how do I use it in MonoDevelop (Mono for Android - C#)?

Comment: No different to the way you would use it in .NET. See here, it is one website of many that attempt to explain how to use it: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx ...admittedly documentation on the HTMLAgilityPack is sparse.

Comment: I used it .NET, but the one for android doesn't have .dll (only .cs files)so I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile it from code
Download the source

go into

```
\htmlagilitypack-99964\Branches\1.4.0\HtmlAgilityPack
```

Edit the `csproj` change to

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" />
```

Save and load

Fix errors

Trace -> Debug

Remove block

```
 if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(new DnsPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
        {
            //do something.... not at full trust
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(extension, false);
                if (reg != null) contentType = (string)reg.GetValue("", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                contentType = def;
            }
        }
```

Remove block

```
 if (SecurityManager.IsGranted(new RegistryPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + contentType, false);
                if (reg != null) ext = (string)reg.GetValue("Extension", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ext = def;
            }
        }
```

Use the `dll` in the `bin/debug` folder